# *solved* How can I check if all rows in a numpy array equals to 1 when the number of arrays differ?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a way to test (element wise) which rows in N number of arrays that are equal to 1. I know there are good ways to do this when we know the number of arrays which I've found searching around. However, in my case, I will not (in a time efficent manner) be able to keep track of the number of array in which I want to test this on.  Below is the solution and desired output when comparing two arrays.

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
A = np.array([1,2,3])
B = np.array([1,1,1])
C = np.logical_and(A==1,B==1)


array([ True, False, False])
```

I could also use np.where(A==1) if I have an array of floats with multiple arrays. However, this only gives me the occurances if one value is equal to 1.

Example array: (note that it wont always be 3 arrays but can be 5 or 15 as well).

```
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

Comment: A row can't be equal to 1. What are you talking about?

Comment: It sounds like there might be some sort of reduction operation you want to perform that you haven't communicated clearly.

Comment: I meant where all elements in the same row are equal to 1. So in reference to the array above, each value in row 101 are 1 so my desired method would then return True. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Sounds like you need [`numpy.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) with an `axis` parameter.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112supportsMonica. That did the trick!